# How to test iOS fido2 BLE authenticator implementation?

Tags: android, ios, webauthn, fido

I'm trying to develop a fido2 BLE authenticator for iOS platform. As far as I know, android can be tested with OSX desktop chrome(which supports fido2) and fido2 conformance tool. When it comes to iOS, the only way I knew is using 'fido2 conformance tool' which has lots of bugs and couldn't test the app properly.

Is there any other way to test fido2 iOS authenticator implementation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple doesn't allow us to set Service Data field for bluetooth advertisement while current Chrome version is detecting to-be-paired device by that field. So we can not do the pair with iOS device formally.

Temporarily, there are 2 ways to pair with iOS device our of WebAuthn:

1. Using chrome://bluetooth-internals to detect & pair with iOS device
2. Using WebBluetooth

After paired, we can just test with WebAuthn on Chrome

Comment: thanks for the reply.  chrome://bluetooth-internals, Not listing my authenticator instead it showing my device ble name. when I try to connect getting "UNSUPPORTED_DEVICE"

Comment: Can connect my authenticator using Bluetooth-internals. But after selecting 'Bluetooth' as security key in webauthn, my authenticator is not listed for pairing. how to pair ?

Comment: I tested my ios advertisement data with u2f in chrome android. Do we need to set device_info(0x180A)? I guess by default iOS provide this service. But it is missing "firmware revision string" characteristic, is it because of that? if so how to add that missing charac to device_info?

Comment: Android chrome works differently. My iOS is working fine with Chrome on Desktop. You message me here for convenient talk: https://www.facebook.com/quocbao.hoa